# Can't get google map to display on wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google maps api and am using it to put a map on my wordpress page and get the location of the user. So far, I have kept the following code in my header.php file with myapikey replaced with my actual api key.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=myapikey"></script>
```

I also have a wordpress page with the following code. This code works when I keep it on a html file. However, when I put this code on my wordpress page, I don't even get the map to show. I am using Google Maps API v3 Geolocation. Could someone please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100%; width: 100%; top: -100px;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        //Html five geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                             position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map: map,
              position: pos,
              content: "HTML5 is used."
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
      }
      function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
          var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
          var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }

        var options = {
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
          content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us what you have done in wordpress, how did you include this page?

Comment: For my wordpress page, I went to pages and added a new page. With that page, I kept the above html code inside the Text box. I have been able to create a working google map on my page before, but the problem seems to occur when I try to use Geolocation and libraries=places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't paste the complete document into the editor, what you put into the editor is expected to be te content of your page, it may be almost anything that you would put into the  of a HTML-page(no html, head and body).

script and style always include either via the header/footer of the theme or via a plugin.

Comment: I put the code into my script and style code into the header file and it worked. Thank you so much.